# How to maintain join node in Firebase db

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, nosql

Sorry for the cryptic title.
I'm new to Firebase db. I'm using it with AngularFire (ng4).
I'm working on a website about stallions (horses). Each stallion has an owner and an owner can have multiple stallions. Each stallion is also registered with one or more studbooks and a studbook has multiple stallions.
I now have 3 top-level nodes: stallions, owners and studbooks.

I have a form to add or edit a stallion. This form has select boxes with all possible owners and all possible studbooks. When I save the stallion the whole owner node and the studbook nodes are saved in the stallion node. This part is working fine.

A new page will show the details of the studbook and all its stallions. With this part, I'm struggling. I've read a lot and I think I need a join node (studbook_stallions) where I put in the studbook key and all stallion keys (or whole items?) that are in part of this studbook. I'm a right, so far?

When adding a stallion I can also add an entry in the join node, but what about when modifying a stallion. Do I first need to check if the stallion is already in the join node? Won't this effect performance?

This is my add stallion method:

```
addStallion(alias: string, formValues: Stallion): any {
  formValues.updated = firebase.database["ServerValue"]["TIMESTAMP"];
  return this.af.database.ref().child("stallions/" + alias).set(formValues);
}
```

And this is my update stallion method:

```
updateStallion(alias: string, formValues: Stallion) {
  formValues.updated = firebase.database["ServerValue"]["TIMESTAMP"];
  this.af.object("stallions/" + alias).update(formValues);
}
```

How to change these methods to also modify the join node (studbook_stallions)?

And a similar question. I now have the whole owner node in my stallion node. How do I update this owner node when I update my owner?
This is my update owner method:

```
updateOwner(alias: string, formValues: Owner) {
  formValues.updated = firebase.database["ServerValue"]["TIMESTAMP"];
  this.af.object("stallions/" + alias).update(formValues);
  // Also update in stallion node:
  // ?????????????
}
```

[**Edit**]

This is my stallion node:

[image]

This is my owner node:

[image]

At this moment the stallion node has the full owner data, but the owner node does not yet have the full stallions data. I will change is soon.

I don't yet have modeled the studbook, because I'm not sure what the best workflow is. My studbook will have multiple stallions. When I update my stallion I also need to update the same stallion in the studbook node. But how do I know which stallion in the studbook node? And the same the other way round. I update my studbook and I now need to update the studbook in several stallion nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your database structure here would help a lot to visualize your database but I think what you're looking for here is to update multiple child nodes simultaneously, and this is how you would do it:

```
var childUpdates = [];

childUpdates[ '/stallions/' + yourStallionID ] = someDataHere;

childUpdates[ '/stallionOwners/stallions/' + yourStallionID ] = someOtherDataHere;

firebase.database().ref().update(childUdates);
```

This would ensure that both child nodes get updated simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updating multiple child nodes at once would be my next question ;) My main problem is how to know which nodes to update. When I update my studbook or owner which stallion do I need to update? I edited my question and added the db structure.

Comment: No problem! Well to do that, you would only need to keep track of the stallion id you would like to update. How do you define your Stallion object ?